# set network on GNU/Linux Mint

Tags: networking, linux-mint, proxy, configure, domain

I am migrating to Linux, but I only have experience with Windows. So, I'm afraid I'll run into many difficulties. In Windows in my workenvironment I configure the following things:

- IPv4 address
- Netmask
- Gateway
- Wins
- Proxy

And finish by putting the PC on the (Active Directory) domain.

I'm not a networking-specialist but I know that we use a virtual samba3 server and I want to access my shared files.
I want to configure Mint so that I can do those things.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mentioning that your company uses AD ("the domain"), so it's a rather professional setup. This means that most likely a DHCP server will also be available. During the installation Mint tests this so the network-configuration will automatically work.

If somehow this is not case: Click on the network-icon on the bottom-right of your desktop, choose "Network Settings", click on the settings-gear and fill in the requested information just like you would do it on your Windows system.

For access to your files you don't have to worry about placing your system in the domain. Instead you can more-or-less copy the Windows way of accessing your files:

- Windows: You open the file-explorer and type `\\name-of-the-fileserver` in the location bar
- Mint: You open Nemo (Mint's file-explorer) and type `smb://name-of-the-fileserver`  in the location bar

I and some on my colleagues use Mint, we work for a large Windows-oriented company, it never failed for us

Comment: Thanks! Garo It works very fine =)

Comment: In that case, could flag it as best answer and/or rate it up ? Thanks ;-)